# Connecting to ACR from our AVD's docker destop

Tags: azure, containers

We have an ACR in our RG, and we have our AVD in same subscription as well. I had admin user enabled on ACR and when I try to do docker login from AVD to our ACR with its credentials with gives 'no host or ACR found'

I have tried creating private endpoints, linking virtual networks. Still cannot figure out what is missing

I have tried creating private endpoints, linking virtual networks. Still cannot figure out what is missing

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce same in my environment I got the results successfully like below.***

First, I have created ***Azure Virtual Desktop host pools*** with virtual machine like below:

[image]

In ***application group*** try to ***Add assignment*** of user like below:

Then in RG -> access control (IAM) -> Make sure to Add role assignment to the user as below:

- **`Virtual machine user login`**
- **`virtual machine administrator login`**

[image]

Created a ***workspace*** and try to add your ***application groups -> Add -> select desktop application -> select like below:***

[image]

Then in your ***hostpool*** -> ***Total machine*** -> you can session ***hosts status as available*** like below

[image]

Created ***Azure container registry:***

[image]

Now, try to login with your user which you select in assignment and then try to login with same user to[remote desktop web client](https://client.wvd.microsoft.com/arm/webclient/index.html)

Once login with session desktop open ***Microsoft edge*** try to install [Docker desktop](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/) then in start bar -> search Docker desktop -> *run as administrator* it automatically clone, you will get the screen like below:

[image]

***When I try to docker login from azure virtual desktop it successfully logged-in like below:***

```
docker login <Login server>
```

[image]